# Motorcycle V-Twin CV carbs riding poorly on 1/4-3/4 throttle after carb rebuild

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, rebuild, lean, carb-synchronization

**Background:**

The bike Suzuki Intruder VS1400 model 2000, ran fantastic, but started to stall on idle when I used old fuel in it.

**What I did:**

I cleaned the two CV carbs. Didn't replace anything.

I found the floats too high, I adjusted them according to factory specs, about 2mm lower.

Resynchronized the idle and throttle using Carbtune from Morgan.

Adjusted the pilot screw using Colortune from Morgan also.

**Symptoms now:**

- Idle runs great.
- Little hesitant when snapping the throttle on neutral.
- Under load, 2 gear and above, 1/4-3/4 throttle:

  - Hesitates
  - No power
  - Pops on acceleration
  - Heats up more than usual.
  - Gear rattles
- On WOT, it picks up power after one second in WOT, but not as strong as before.
- Spark plugs are yellowish but clean and dry. No signs of melting. but I didn't ride the bike other than 500 meters test drives.
- **I sprayed starter spray on the intake boots, no rpm difference, no intake leak as far as I can tell.**

**More information:**

- I can't tell which carb pops because both exhausts are on the same side.
- The diaphrams are in good shape, I can lift the slide by blowing into the carb intake ventury, and it goes down normally, with some suction sound. which I believe to be good.
- I cleaned it with brake cleaner and compressed air, it was already clean, no plugged holes anywhere.
- I've repeated the procedure another time in case I missed a step, but no change.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: "I found the floats too high, I adjusted them according to factory specs, about 2mm lower." Put them back to how you found them, this may have been done to solve the issue you are having.

Comment: You cleaned the carbs. You need to be *scrupulously* clean on that job. The merest whisp of a fibre in a jet can upset the carburation.

Comment: @WeatherVane, you're right, I was, I learned that lesson from the past, all intakes and hoses are covered all the time to avoid any dust particles from entering.

Comment: @Moab, yeah, I know it was either too high or too low, I can't seem to remember any more. But I'll try both directions and see.

Answer (score 2):

The symptoms you describe (hesitant, low power, running hot) point to a lean condition. It sounds like you may have set the floats too low, I'd set the floats back to where they were and see if that improves the situation.

Comment: Low float means when you put the carb upside down (almost), the floats are closer to the carburetor body, the distance was larger in the past, I brought them 2mm closer to the body. Which should mean more fuel in the bowl, doesn't it? I should expect the opposite effect shouldn't I?

Comment: I'd assumed you meant that he adjustments you made were in relation to the normal orientation of the carb. I'd still put the floats back to where they were and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Ok I'll do that, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's the one thing you changed @Aus. Going back to how it was eliminates that factor.

Comment: "Low float means when you put the carb upside down" actually it does not. Low and high are relevant to the normal position of the carb. Low in the float bowl or high in the float bowl.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Moab, however that is inline with what I saw before, it was "low" as you describe in the past which should be "leaner in the past" now I don't get how making it higher causes it to run lean. But my opinion is doesn't matter, will test setting the float lower then higher +-2mm and see how it goes. Eliminating that factor at least as GdD said.

Comment: @GdD As I suspected, lowering the floats 2mm below specs made it run lean across the rpm range. Idles fine but once I apply any throttle, it goes lean and stays lean even on idle. Going to try bringing it high 2mm above specs and come back.

Comment: @GdD I tried the 2mm too high setting and it was good on idle, 1st and second gear, but it rapidly lost power on the 3rd gear. just no power and gear rattle, some pops here and there on deceleration. Ideas?